# AWS Postgres OID stability during fail over

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, npgsql

Does [AWS RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/) offer any guarantees about the stability of OIDs during failover or hardware provisioning?

I'm asking this because whilst testing a local Postgres Database, I dropped and recreated the database which contains a `citext` type column and encountered the error `The field 'name' has a type currently unknown to Npgsql (OID 1393966)`. I realise this is because OIDs aren't persisted across database drop and create, and [Npgsql caches column type OIDs](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/789).

I'm new to Azure and AWS, but I've found that Azure connections are unreliable because it can shuffle databases around "transparently" to the client. I'm unsure if AWS has similar behaviour, but I've read the fail-over between regions is transparent. I'm concerned that transparently switching server for any reason could change the OID of `citext` and cause the application to start failing - or worse have the wrong behaviour on the chance of OID collision.

Are my fears unfounded? Is there a way of detecting a connection switch and call [Connection.ReloadTypes()](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/824)?

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL in general doesn't guarantee type OID stability for types created by extensions (as opposed to built-in types which are stable). AFAIK this is the case in PostgreSQL in general, not just RDS.

This is one reason why Npgsql loads types *by name* - the first time it connects to a given database (or more precisely, to a given connection string), all types are loaded and known type names (e.g. `citext`) are matched to the specific database's type OID for that name. This information is cached on the connection string for the lifetime of the application.

If, during the lifetime of the application, a type OID changes (because that type's extension was dropped and recreated), then `NpgsqlConnection.ReloadTypes()` indeed has to be called to reload the name/OID information.

Your question on failure is indeed interesting... I don't know anything about how RDS implements its fail-overs, but have you actually seen the citext type OID differing across two geographical instances?

Comment: I haven't setup RDS in different Regions yet - this is more of a theoretical question since I'm currently porting from self-hosted SQL Server to hosted Postgres and trying to do as much research to avoid any gotcha's.
Out of interest, how easy do you think it would it be for Npgsql to throw a custom exception which can be caught by the application to decide whether to reload types? Catching NotSupportedException could work I guess, but I don't want false positives.

Comment: I think the code is [here](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/829bbbf4497e3c29815d7178d45618e012276100/src/Npgsql/TypeHandlers/UnknownTypeHandler.cs) but I'm not sure what a NpgsqlSafeReadException is...

Comment: It's certainly possible to throw a specific exception for this, but it seems quite bad if application have to catch it and reload as part of their normal flow... Up to now reloading has only been necessary when the application adds an extension to a database and then wants to use its type(s) in the same application instance...

Comment: I'm assuming (or rather hoping) that part of RDS replication is to ensure total database identity, which would include type OIDs, so this problem simply may not exist. Is there any way you could confirm this?

Comment: I will investigate it further - I agree that it's not a nice experience!

Comment: In case you're interested, I've done some experimentation and it _seems_ that OIDs are stable during failover. I've posted more information in my answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

So with a bit of experimentation, it seems that OIDs can be stable.

I ran the following query every 100ms:

```
select typname, oid, pg_postmaster_start_time(), inet_server_addr()::text
from pg_catalog.pg_type
where typname = 'citext';
```

and logged whenever any of the results changed. I then rebooted my RDS instance with fail over. After a few connection timeouts, the inet_server_addr() changed but the oid didn't. I rebooted again, and the inet_server_addr() reverted back and again the oid stayed the same.

Unless anyone can definitively prove that OIDs change or know the internal implementation details, I'm now confident that OIDs are stable during fail over - but I'm hesitant to say I've proven it just because I haven't proven the opposite

Comment: That's great to know, thanks for taking the time to do this experiment!